# Parse PUSH - Json Open webpage in webview

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform, push

I am looking for help figuring out how to set this up for Android (Java) with Parse Push.

While sending a push with: `{ "alert": "Read this", "articleId": "2" }`

The app will open: myCoolAdress.com/articles/2

EDIT: Added code.

public class ParseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static final String ACTION                       =   "org.app.app.MESSAGE";
public static final String PARSE_EXTRA_DATA_KEY         =   "com.parse.Data";
public static final String PARSE_JSON_CHANNEL_KEY       =   "com.parse.Channel";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String articleId = extras != null ? extras
            .getString("com.parse.Data") : "";
    JSONObject jObject;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(articleId);
        Log.d("Log",
                jObject.getString("articleId")
                        + jObject.getString("action"));
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
 public static final String ACTION                       =   "org.APP.APP.MESSAGE";
public static final String PARSE_EXTRA_DATA_KEY         =   "com.parse.Data";
public static final String PARSE_JSON_CHANNEL_KEY       =   "com.parse.Channel";
public static final String TAG                          =   "articleId";

@Override
//
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );
    JSONObject jObject;
    Log.i("PUSH", String.format("push received: %s", jsonData));
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String articleId = jObject.getString("articleId");
        Log.d("PUSH URL",
                "http://MYaweSOMEapp.com/articles/" + articleId);


        Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("url",  "http://MYaweSOMEapp.com/app/articles/" + articleId);
        webViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(webViewIntent);

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. When you receive a push notification in your `BroadcastListener`, extract the payload.
2. Create a `Notification`.
3. Add a `PendingIntent` to the notification that points to the browser with your URL.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

So, if the user click on your notification, he will be redirected to your website.

Comment: I think i will have to do something like thi@Override
    public void onReccive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String articleId = intent.getAction();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            String int  = json.getString("action");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(myCoolAdress.com/articles/\"articleId");
            context.ApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());

Comment: There is an example, how to extract the payload, in the official documentation. Please have a look:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive 
If you want to know how to open a browser with an URL see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions in https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications ? The section called "Receiving Pushes" has information on how to handle push notifications.

Comment: Yea, but I don't see how it could help me.

Comment: Which parts have you tried and how far have you got?

Comment: I am stuck - and having problems to figure out how/where to start.